# Looping through a Google App script and setting multiple nonconsecutive values

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This was difficult to title without examples and context. Here goes...

I have a Google app script which searches through a column of student ids (*column A on the compiledDATA sheet*) and then sets a value (an award) in column B of the same row. This works fine for a single student id, but I need the script to loop and set the same award value for all of the students in the *GroupAwardIDs* range which is located on a separate sheet called *Group Awards*.

Here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e9uNvikGJI8sJDGwkT7_PZDXX9FvM2x_Q7OK6HUlCo8/edit?usp=sharing) to my sample spreadsheet.

The values to be set are nonconsecutive, and in actual use there may be over a thousand to be set at a time.

How can I achieve this in a quick and efficient way without running into quota issues?

Here's the script (please excuse all the comments - it helps me keep track):

```
function AwardGroup() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var StarLog = sheet.getSheetByName("compiledDATA");
var GroupAward = sheet.getRangeByName("GroupAward").getValue();
var GroupAwardIDs = sheet.getRangeByName("GroupAwardIDs").getValue(); // THESE ARE THE IDS OF STUDENTS WHO WILL RECEIVE THE AWARD. HOW DO SET VALUES FOR ALL AND ONLY THESE IDS?
var IDs = sheet.getRangeByName("StudentIDs").getValues(); // all of the student IDs

for (var i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
if (IDs[i] == "123461") { // THIS WORKS IF HARDCODE A SINGLE ID  
    var rowNumber = i+3; // find row and add 3 to compensate for GroupAward range staring at row 3
    var StarLogCurrent = StarLog.getRange("B"+rowNumber).getValue(); // locates students award log cell using A1 notation
    var appendAward = GroupAward.concat(StarLogCurrent); // prepends new award to previous awards

    StarLog.getRange("B"+rowNumber).setValue(appendAward); //write new star log

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If all values to be written are the same, you can use `RangeList#setValue`. If not, you must either sort the sheet first so you can write it in a single call to `Range#setValues`. If you can't sort this sheet, then you are forced to access and write each one.

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for the suggestion. All the values to be written are the same. So where would I use `RangeList#setValue`?

Comment: Are all values to be written the same? Your sample code constructs the written value from the new award and the previous award(s), which would imply that each written value could be different...

Comment: @tehhowch For this situation, I tried to propose as a feature request. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111317101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put GroupAward ("'Group Awards'!B3") to the column "B" of "compiledDATA" with the same row, when StudentIDs ("compiledDATA!A3:A1000") and GroupAwardIDs ("'Group Awards'!B7:B1002") are the same. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve all GroupAwardIDs.
- Remove empty elements in GroupAwardIDs.
- Search IDs using GroupAwardIDs and put GroupAward when the IDs is the same with GroupAwardIDs.
- Put the values with GroupAward.

#### Modified script :

Please modify as follows.

From :

```
var GroupAwardIDs = sheet.getRangeByName("GroupAwardIDs").getValue(); // THESE ARE THE IDS OF STUDENTS WHO WILL RECEIVE THE AWARD. HOW DO SET VALUES FOR ALL AND ONLY THESE IDS?
var IDs = sheet.getRangeByName("StudentIDs").getValues(); // all of the student IDs

for (var i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
  if (IDs[i] == "123461") { // THIS WORKS IF HARDCODE A SINGLE ID  
    var rowNumber = i+3; // find row and add 3 to compensate for GroupAward range staring at row 3
    var StarLogCurrent = StarLog.getRange("B"+rowNumber).getValue(); // locates students award log cell using A1 notation
    var appendAward = GroupAward.concat(StarLogCurrent); // prepends new award to previous awards
    StarLog.getRange("B"+rowNumber).setValue(appendAward); //write new star log
  }
}
```

To :

```
var GroupAwardIDs = sheet.getRangeByName("GroupAwardIDs").getValues(); // Modified
var IDs = sheet.getRangeByName("StudentIDs").getValues();

// I modified below script.
GroupAwardIDs = GroupAwardIDs.filter(String);
var res = IDs.map(function(e){
  return GroupAwardIDs.filter(function(f){
    return f[0] == e[0]
  }).length > 0 ? [GroupAward] : [""];
});
sheet.getRange("compiledDATA!B3:B1000").setValues(res);
```

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Edit :

You want to add GroupAward to the original values at column B. I understood what you want to do like this. If my understanding is correct, please modify to as follows. In this sample, I used `", "` as the delimiter.

```
var GroupAwardIDs = sheet.getRangeByName("GroupAwardIDs").getValues(); // Modified
var IDs = sheet.getRangeByName("StudentIDs").getValues();

// I modified below script.
var columnB = sheet.getRange("compiledDATA!B3:B1000");
var valColB = columnB.getValues();
GroupAwardIDs = GroupAwardIDs.filter(String);
var res = IDs.map(function(e, i){
  return GroupAwardIDs.filter(function(f){
    return f[0] == e[0]
  }).length > 0 ? [valColB[i][0] ? GroupAward + ", " + valColB[i][0] : GroupAward] : [valColB[i][0]]; // Modified
});
columnB.setValues(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. You understood my question perfectly and your solution works great, however I neglected to mention that the previous awards **(var StarLog)** must be prepended with the new award **(var GroupAward)**. I used `var appendAward = GroupAward.concat(StarLogCurrent);` to concatenate the two variables. How can I use your modification to achieve this?

Comment: @firenemus I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstand your comment, please tell me.

Comment: No inconvenience! You're helping me out. Your solution is almost there and I wish I was knowledgeable enough to figure the rest out from here but there's another issue. Each time the script is run all previous values are erased if that student's ID is not present in the `GroupAwardIDs` . This can't happen. Column B on the compiledDATA sheet is a running log of all awards so they can't be overwritten with blank values. The student IDs will change periodically so not every student will receive an award each time the script runs. I hope this makes sense. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @firenemus You want to leave and use the original values of column B. I understood like this. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? I modified from ``[""]`` to ``[valColB[i][0]]``. If I misunderstand your comment, please tell me.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks so much for your help! Please keep an eye out for me on the exchange. I'm working on a project for my school and I would greatly appreciate any help you could provide. Cheers!

Comment: @firenemus I'm glad your issue was solved. I could also study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: Sorry friend, but I'm having another issue that I didn't recognize immediately. The new value is being set after the old value and it should appear first. In other words, I need the `GroupAwards` to be prepended to the values in `valColB`. How can I change this so the new value is set in front of the previous value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174825/discussion-between-firenemus-and-tanaike).

Comment: @firenemus I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I couldn't notice about what you want. I'm sorry. You want to put the new value to the left of the original value. I understood like this. By this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? I modified ``valColB[i][0] + ", " + GroupAward`` to ``GroupAward + ", " + valColB[i][0]``. I'm really sorry.

Comment: No problem. Everything is working as intended. :) Thanks again for all your help!